# Trim DateTime to Milliseconds From the JsonRequest

Tags: scala, datetime-format, simpledateformat, milliseconds

I am receiving a request having date time like

```
"modified" : "2021-06-11T07:56:53.494074Z"
```

And I am using

```
val df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
```

With the above request I am getting the error

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

If I am sending the request upto three digits after decimal it works
example `"modified": "2021-06-11T07:56:53.012Z"`
Is there a way to trim the request to milliseconds so that it woks or handle the extended request using SimpleDateFormat itself.
Have already read many answers saying  **you cannot use SimpleDateFormat to handle nanoseconds**
So to use java.time package.
Can someone please help with the trim or to support extended digits using SimpleDateFormat itself

Comment: [Works for me](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZWV32CXnQeCCbkWsUfSLzg).

Comment: @Dima Did you tested it sending it as json request

Comment: I am just saying that the problem as described in your question is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.")
```

Append 'dot' after seconds it should drop nanoseconds.

Comment: You sending this to server and server is giving you that error which you mentioned?